# Can't access class attribute

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to load an Tkinter UI that should run in its own thread. After creating an instance of the UI, I get this error when trying to access the attribute:  `line 18, in do_move: self.game_ui.setTile(4, 0, 0) AttributeError: 'Play' object has no attribute 'game_ui'`

I'm not sure if I messed up the threading or something else, but I also notice that `self.game_ui.drawBoard(..)` does not actually update the UI.

```
import GUI
import game


class Play:
    def __init__(self):
        print ('Init')
        self.game_core = game.Board()
        print(self.game_core.tiles)
        self.game_ui = GUI.getNewBoardWindow(self.keylistener)
        self.game_ui.drawBoard(self.game_core.tiles)

    def keylistener(self, event):
        self.do_move((event.keycode-38) % 4)

    def do_move(self, key):
        print(key)
        self.game_ui.setTile(4, 0, 0)


def main():
    Play()


main()
```

Where the GUI is like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread


class GUI(Frame, Thread):
    cellColors = {0: "#CCC0B3", 2: "#eee4da", 4: "#ede0c8", 8: "#f2b179", 16: "#f59563", 32: "#f67c5f", 64: "#f65e3b", 128: "#edcf72", 256: "#edcc61", 512: "#edc850", 1024: "#edc53f", 2048: "#edc22e", 4096: "#3c3a32"}
    boardSize = 4

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="#BBADA0")
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.cells = []
        self.initUI(150)
        self.pack()
        self.start()
        self.parent.mainloop()

    def initUI(self, cellSize):
        for row in range(self.boardSize-1, -1, -1):
            self.cells.append([])
            for column in range(self.boardSize):
                cell = Frame(self, width=cellSize, height=cellSize)
                cell.grid(row=row, column=column, padx=4, pady=4)
                cell.pack_propagate(0)

                tile = Label(cell, bg="#CCC0B3", font=("Helvetica", 35, "bold"))
                tile.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
                self.cells[-1].append(tile)

    def setTile(self, value, x, y):
        print(value)
        self.cells[y][x].config({
            "bg": GUI.cellColors[min(4096, value)],
            "fg": ("#776E65" if value < 8 else "#f9f6f2"),
            "text": str(value) if value else ''})

    def drawBoard(self, board):
        for col in range(len(board)):
            for row in range(len(board)):
                self.setTile(board[col][row], col, row)


def getNewBoardWindow(listener=None):
    root = Tk()
    root.title("2048")
    if listener:
        root.bind("<Key>", listener)

    app = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
    #mainThread = Thread(target=root.mainloop)
    #mainThread.start()
    return app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start the mainloop `root.mainloop()` in `getNewBoardWindow()`, which in turn  will return `app` that will be assinged to `self.game_ui` in `Play`. Since `getNewBoardWindow()` cannot return while the GUI is running, `self.game_ui` cannot exist.

You can fix this by returning `root` along with `app`:

```
def getNewBoardWindow(listener=None):
    root = Tk()
    root.title("2048")
    if listener:
        root.bind("<Key>", listener)
    app = GUI(root)
    return app, root
```

and in `Play`:

```
class Play:
    def __init__(self):
        print ('Init')
        self.game_core = game.Board()
        print(self.game_core.tiles)
        self.game_ui, self.root = GUI.getNewBoardWindow(self.keylistener)
        self.game_ui.drawBoard(self.game_core.tiles)
        self.root.mainloop()
```

I would recommend to re-designed your program so that `root.mainloop()` is at the end of the main program, not inside an `__init__()`.

Comment: So I have to call start `root.mainloop()` in `Play`, after assignment?

Comment: Yes, I added a suggestion how you could do it.